# How to validate existing file in Yii2 framework

Tags: file, validation, yii2

I want to use [FileValidator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html) on existing file - how to do that?
As I know, FileValidator works only on instances of UploadedFile class. How to validate my file if it's already uploaded?

There's some good solution or I must write my own ExistingFileValidator?

**Edit**: more details:
I want to do it in my model this way:

Model rules:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['myExistingFile'], 'file',
            'maxSize' => self::MAX_SIZE,
            'tooBig' => 'msg',
            'minSize' => self::MIN_SIZE,
            'tooSmall' => 'msg',
            'extensions' => self::VALID_EXTENSIONS,
            'mimeTypes' => self::VALID_MIME_TYPES,
            'wrongExtension' => 'msg',
            'wrongMimeType' => 'msg',
        ],
    ];
}
```

Controller action:

```php
public function actionFoo()
{
    $model->myExistingFile = 'path/to/file.ext';
    if (!$model->validate()) {
        // file is invalid
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of validation are you looking for?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve. Please provide more details.

Comment: Sorry for that. I provide more details now.

Comment: Interesting question. Yes, that would require an own class, I think. Or possibly, it could work if you overwrite the UploadedFile class that the FileValidator is working with and use an instance of it. Acutally, the uploaded file is a local file. Your file is not in the temp dir and don't need to be saved somewhere, but the rest is the same. Would that help?

Comment: Please visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975234/server-side-file-validation-dont-work-in-yii-2-0 I've explained solutions.

Answer (score 2):

An simple inline validator would be sufficient:

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        ...
        ['myAttributeWithLocalFilePath', function ($attribute, $params) {
            if (!file_exists($this->$attribute)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'myAttributeWithLocalFilePath has no valid file path.');
            }
        }],
        ...
    ];
}
```

Of course you can do further checks: if the attribute is empty (though you could use the *required* validator for this) or the file is empty. As long as you don't want to build a reusable, configurable or complex validation tool that gets realized with its own class (derived from Validator) an inline validation is sufficient.

More info [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators).

Comment: Yes, I know that it can be done this way, but it's not good solution. Please look at my question - I provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
'skipOnEmpty' => false,
```

in rule

Answer (score 0):

please visit this  link:

link: [Server Side file validation Don't work in Yii.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32975234/server-side-file-validation-dont-work-in-yii-2-0)

I've explained solutions