# Server Side file validation Don't work in Yii.2.0

Tags: php, file, validation, yii2

Is the `FileValidator` class in Yii2 only supports clientside validation ?

I written the file upload system with the use of code :

in model:

```
 public function rules() {
    return [


        [['allAllowedFileType'], 'safe'],

        [['allAllowedFileType'], 'file',
            'extensions'=>'jpg',
            'mimeTypes' => 'image/jpeg'],

    ];
}
```

in controller:

```
 public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new File();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // get the uploaded file instance. for multiple file uploads
        // the following data will return an array
       $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'allAllowedFileType');
        // store the source file name
        $model->name = $image->name;
        $ext = end((explode(".", $image->name)));

        // generate a unique file name
        $avatar = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";


        $path = 'c:wamp/www/' . $avatar;
        if($model->validate()&&$model->save(0)){
            $image->saveAs($path);
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id'=>$model->id]);
        } else {
            // error in saving model
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model'=>$model,
    ]);
}
```

in view :

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation' => true,
            'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'] // important
]);

echo $form->field($model, "allAllowedFileType")->fileInput();

?>
```

When a invalid file(for example file by `.php` extention) is loaded .
Only client-side validation is done.

Once the form is set as follows:

```
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation' => false,
            'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'] // important
]);
```

No error message is given and the files will not be Server side validated.

also i tried to set  the variable (`$model->allAllowedFileType`) as follows :

```
$model->allAllowedFileType=$_FILES['File'];
```

I uploaded invalid file for example file by `.exe` extention) and  execute validate function, the error message wont be displayed.and `$model->errors` is empty.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new File();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {


       $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'allAllowedFileType');

      ...

       $model->allAllowedFileType=$_FILES['File'];

        if($model->validate()){

           //save file

        } else {

             die(var_dump($model->errors));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model'=>$model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `'skipOnEmpty' => false` and maybe `checkExtensionByMimeType` to your rules.

```
[['allAllowedFileType'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'jpg', 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => true],
```

At least i have this running in my form where i haven't disabled client side validation.
Not sure if you have enabled all required php extensions `fileinfo` is required.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-filevalidator.html

Answer (score 0):

I find solution.

With yii2 is a little difference in yii1 Upload file:

You have set as follow:

old-code:
with this code $model->allAllowedfileType not set and $model->validate() not work.

```
           $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'allAllowedfileType ');
```

replace with:(with this code $model->allAllowedfileType set and $model->validate() work.)

```
            $model->allAllowedFileType = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'allAllowedFileType');
```

i hope it usefull.:)